# Cant add bellow the title for the pictures

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to add the titles of this 2 image below them. But every time I try to add either `h` or `p` the text goes to do the right side instead to the bottom.
What am I doing wrong? Im just starting to learn html and I really like it but I'm stuck, and this is for my exam. Need help in this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Comenzando la Fotografia</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenido">
            <div id="pagetitle">
                <h1>Comenzando la Fotografia</h1>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav_item">
                    <li><a href="index.html" id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paisajes.html" style="text-decoration: underline">Paisajes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="retratos.html" style="text-decoration: underline">Retratos</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <section id="central">
                    <img id="centralpic" style="align-content: center" src="img/paisajecentral.png" alt="imagencentral" title="paisaje1" width="730" height="413">
                </section>
                <article id="sidebyside">
                    <img id="leftpic" src="img/portadapng.jpg" alt="imagenderecha" title="paisaje2" width="640" height="400">
                    <img id="rightpic" src="img/woman.jpg" alt="imagenizquierda" title="retrato1" width="736" height="1104">
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="piedepagina">
                <div id="footer1">
                    <section id="contact">
                        <h3>Contacto</h3>
                        <p>Correo: <a href="mailtome:rdelarosa042019@gmail.com">rdelarosa042019@gmail.com</a></p>
                        <p>Calle 3ra Avenida la Paz</p>
                        <p>Telefono: 220-0000</p>
                    </section>
                    <section id="terms">
                        <h3>Terminos</h3>
                        <p>Nos reservamos los derechos de autor y todo contenido es privado</p>
                    </section>
                    <section id="redes_sociales">
                        <h3>Redes Sociales</h3>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="icon/facebook.png">Comenzando la Fotografia</a>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="icon/twitter.png">@comenzandolafotografia</a>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><img src="icon/instagram.png">#comenzandolafotografia</a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="rights">
                        <h3>Derechos</h3>
                        <p>Ruben De La Rosa</p>
                        <p>Copyrights&#169;-2017</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


    body{
    background-color: #02010a;
    color: white;
}
.contenido{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#pagetitle{
    background-color: #5b7989;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10xp;
}
h1{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #02010a;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a{
    color: white;
}
#navigation{
    float: right;
}
#nav_item{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline;
}
#central{
    background-color: #82c3a6;
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#centralpic{
    align-content: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#sidebyside{
    background-color: #d5c75f;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-content: center;
}
#leftpic{
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px auto;;
}
#rightpic{
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px 70px auto;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `<img>` element to `<figure>` element and after `<img>` element add `<figcaption>` element. So your code will be something like this :

```
<figure>
<img id="leftpic" src="img/portadapng.jpg" alt="imagenderecha" title="paisaje2" width="640" height="400">
<figcaption>Your text here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Hope it help you out.

Comment: Ok, that help me a lot, but now im having another issue. In the footer I have "contact, terms, socials and rights" and I need to put them as a column, I now I need to use flex-wrap or display flex box is not having any change